# Azure C# v2 Function: Entire table processed instead of portion of table

Tags: c#, azure

I am writing a basic C# Azure v2 timer function in order to read the first ten lines of an Azure Storage Table. However, when I run my program, the size of the list storing the role assignments (`tablePortion`) is `10000`. This seems strange, considering that my while loop only goes for 10 iterations. Below is my code:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%TimerTriggerPeriod%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    // Authenticate access into the database's Azure Table Storage
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

    // Retrieve the role assignments table
    CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("OneAuthZRoleAssignments");

    // Test out retrieving a small portion from the role assignments table (10 rows)
    var tablePortion = new List<RoleAssignment>();
    TableContinuationToken token = null;
    var rowCount = 0;
    do
    {
        var queryResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<RoleAssignment>(), token);
        tablePortion.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
        token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
        rowCount++;
    } while (rowCount < 10);

    Console.WriteLine(tablePortion.Count); // Output: 10000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your program is working fine, since it does what you ask it to do.

When calling the method table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync you send it a new TableQuery instance without specifying a filter or pagination, which means it will return the default amount (which is also the maximum amount) of 1,000 items - as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.tablequery?view=azure-java-legacy)

If what you want is to receive only 10 items, you could make the call outside a while loop and send a pagination of 10 when creating the filter for TableQuery.